# Error to downloads the library(NeuralNetTools)

Tags: r

I am unable to download the library(NeuralNetTools)

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘NeuralNetTools’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.5 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
```

I have tried using R-studio and R base and received the same error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘NeuralNetTools’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.5 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
```